# Build DOM recursive with Express-Handlebars/NodeJs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I have a JSON object that I pass to my handlebars file. You can have a look at this object here

https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=ea86167f5da7403fbdb6bfaf936bc404

I pass my JSON file as a JSON object to the hbs file

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const jsonFile = fs.readFileSync('treeView.json', 'utf8');
    const fileContent = JSON.parse(jsonFile);

    res.render('treeView', {
       treeView: fileContent
    });
});
```

and try to create the HTML elements based on this object data. I tried to create JavaScript-Handlebars-Pseudo Code to write down what I want to achieve

```
<div class="folder">
    TreeView
    <!-- getItems( {{treeView}} )    start with the top level item       --> 
</div>

<!-- 

function getItems(currentItem) {
    const children = currentItem.children; // try to get all child items
    const isFile = !children; // is it a file or a folder?

    if (isFile) { // create child container of type "file"

        <div class="file">
            {{ current.name }}
        </div>

    } else { // create child container of type "folder"

        <div class="folder">
            {{ current.name }}

            <div class="container">

            for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) { // recursive call for the children of the current folder
                const currentChildItem = children[i];
                getItems(currentChildItem);
            }

            </div>

        </div>

    }
}

-->
```

I hope my example shows that I want to create a recursive call that creates div containers as children of their current parent div.

---

**Edit:**

The HTML result would be

```css
.folder {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.file {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="folder">
  TreeView
  <div class="container">
    <div class="folder">
      Section 1
      <div class="container">
        <div class="folder">
          Section 1.1
          <div class="container">
            <div class="file">
              Section 1.1.1
            </div>
            <div class="file">
              Section 1.1.2
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="file">
          Section 1.2
        </div>
        <div class="file">
          Section 1.3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="file">
      Section 2
    </div>
    <div class="folder">
      Section 3
      <div class="container">
        <div class="file">
          Section 3.1
        </div>
        <div class="file">
          Section 3.2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `{{#each}}` statement for templating using Handlebars as such:

```
<div class="folder">
        {{treeView.name}}
        {{#each treeView.children}}
            <div class="container">
                {{name}}
                {{#if children}}
                    {{#each children}}
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="file">
                            {{name}}
                            {{file}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {{/each}}
                {{else}}
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="file">
                            {{name}}
                            {{file}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {{/if}}
            </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
```

Comment: yes but this would only work for the first level of children right? This is not a recursive function

Comment: Do you want to render those divs dynamically in real-time?

Comment: when rendering the file I want to build them recursively